# Linq-to-Entities query result that used params from multiple tables/Dbs

Tags: linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

Greetings Everyone 
I am using EF6 and VS13 Free Community. 
I followed a database First Approach. 
I currently have a project (**.net mvc**) that contains multiple databases and tables
i am using the Entities & Linq queries and i couldn't figure out how to use the result of the queries i create when it's inside an if statement i saw solution but it only works when i use a single table not multiple ones. 
**Example :**

```
var query = from varA in db1.table_name
        from varB in db2.table_name
    where
    varA.X = varB.X
    select new
    {
      varA.stuff,
      varB.something
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved didn't search deep enough
a foreach did it for me

```
foreach (var result in query)
{
   ...
}
```